# WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm saving and loading a Keras model with some custom layers (even though I'm not sure if custom layers have anything to do with the issue). For the record, I'm not saving the model myself but it's done through TFX's Pusher component. At the time of loading, I get a few warnings:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph. For example, in the saved checkpoint object, `model.layer.weight` and `model.layer_copy.weight` reference the same variable, while in the current object these are two different variables. The referenced variables are:(<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7f1d0c557190> and <keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f1d0c557f10>).
WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph. For example, in the saved checkpoint object, `model.layer.weight` and `model.layer_copy.weight` reference the same variable, while in the current object these are two different variables. The referenced variables are:(<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7f1d0c5577c0> and <Layers.SingleOutputWithName.SingleOutputWithName object at 0x7f1d0c4cde80>).
WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph. For example, in the saved checkpoint object, `model.layer.weight` and `model.layer_copy.weight` reference the same variable, while in the current object these are two different variables. The referenced variables are:(<keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f1d0c4cd7c0> and <keras.saving.legacy.saved_model.load.TensorFlowTransform>TransformFeaturesLayer object at 0x7f1d0c557e20>).
WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph. For example, in the saved checkpoint object, `model.layer.weight` and `model.layer_copy.weight` reference the same variable, while in the current object these are two different variables. The referenced variables are:(<keras.saving.legacy.saved_model.load.TensorFlowTransform>TransformFeaturesLayer object at 0x7f1d0c557e20> and <keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f1d0d5e1a00>).
WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph. For example, in the saved checkpoint object, `model.layer.weight` and `model.layer_copy.weight` reference the same variable, while in the current object these are two different variables. The referenced variables are:(<keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f1d0c4cd7c0> and <keras.saving.legacy.saved_model.load.TensorFlowTransform>TransformFeaturesLayer object at 0x7f1d0c557e20>).
```

My question is, are these warnings important? Do I need to do something about them? I'm asking this because the model loads as far as I can tell, and it's working. But at the same time, I cannot be sure if these warnings are messing with the output of the model or not.

The model itself is rather straightforward. No weight sharing or anything complex. It just includes some custom layers, like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers


@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class SingleOutputWithName(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, label_name: str, **kwargs):
        super(SingleOutputWithName, self).__init__()
        self.label_name = label_name

    def call(self, x):
        return {self.label_name: x,
                'dummy': x}

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config['label_name'] = self.label_name
        return config
```

Does anyone know anything about these warnings?

Comment: These are just warnings with some information which you can suppress using - `import logging, os`
`logging.disable(logging.WARNING)`
`os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"` code on top of your code.